# How to use a ViewFlipper with a Gridview with a ImageView with a Textview?

Tags: android, gridview, textview, imageview, viewflipper

help me, I need to create a viewFlipper that contains a number of dynamic gridview that contains an ImageView and a TextView.

how to do this?
thanks,